VSC cannot see newly installed module
I wanted to use this new ngx-mail-sender module (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mail-sender) in my Angular application. So I followed the instructions and installed it. I see the folder sitting there in the node_modules folder, but when I try to import from it in app.module.ts I get the following:
Cannot find module 'ngx-mail-sender' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)
along with a red squiggly line under the import path. I've scoured Google and, while I've found other with this issue, they all solve it by restarting VSC, or clearing the npm cache, resetting the baseUrl in tconfig.json, etc. I've tried every solution I can find, but none work.
Has anyone had this issue and know what might fix it?
Thanks!

Please show the exact command you used to install the module.

in the src folder of the project I used npm install ngx-mail-sender
